# PHP - "Notice: Undefined variable"

Tags: php, php-7

Estou fazendo a implementação de um código escrito em PHP 5 para PHP 7, entretanto, estou recebendo esse aviso (é um formulário), quando preenchido os notice somem, e ficam normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo:

```
<?php function base64($string)
{
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = ('AES-256-CBC');
    $secret_key = ('altere-a-chave');
    $secret_iv = ('altere-a-chave');
    $key = hash(('sha256') , $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash(('sha256') , $secret_iv) , 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = ($output);
    return $output;
}
if (empty($_POST))
{
    echo ('<style>#preview{display:none !important;}</style>');
}
else
{
    echo ('<style>#preview{display:block !important;}</style>');
}
if (empty($_POST))
{
    $buttonStatus = ('Start Encrypt');
    $buttonColor = ('#656565');
}
else
{
    $buttonStatus = ('Encrypted');
    $buttonColor = ('#337ab7');
}
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    extract($_POST);
    // <!-- Qltys -->
    $EncodeAuto = ($_POST[('Auto') ]);
    $EncodeFull = ($_POST[('FullHD') ]);
    $EncodeHD = ($_POST[('HD') ]);
    $EncodeSD = ($_POST[('M_SD') ]);
    $EncodeLOW = ($_POST[('LOW') ]);
    // <!-- Infos -->
    $EncodeTitle = ($_POST[('title') ]);
    $EncodeDesc = ($_POST[('description') ]);
    $EncodeImage = ($_POST[('background') ]);
    $EncodeCC = ($_POST[('captions') ]);
    $EncodeLogo = ($CONFIG[('SiteLogo') ]);
}

if (!isset($_SERVER[('HTTPS') ]))
{
    $dominio = ('http://') . $_SERVER[('SERVER_NAME') ] . ('/');
    $protoStatus = ('Seu protocolo e HTTP (SSL Desativado)');
}
else
{
    $dominio = ('https://') . $_SERVER[('SERVER_NAME') ] . ('/');
    $protoStatus = ('Seu protocolo e HTTPS (SSL Ativado)');
}

$jw7 = $dominio . ('admin/encrypt/jw7.php?auto=') . $EncodeAuto . ('&fullhd=') . $EncodeFull . ('&hd=') . $EncodeHD . ('&m_sd=') . $EncodeSD . ('&low=') . $EncodeLOW . ('&title=') . $EncodeTitle . ('&desc=') . $EncodeDesc . ('&background=') . $EncodeImage . ('&captions=') . $EncodeCC . ('&logo=') . $EncodeLogo;
$jw8 = $dominio . ('admin/encrypt/jw8.php?auto=') . $EncodeAuto . ('&fullhd=') . $EncodeFull . ('&hd=') . $EncodeHD . ('&m_sd=') . $EncodeSD . ('&low=') . $EncodeLOW . ('&title=') . $EncodeTitle . ('&desc=') . $EncodeDesc . ('&background=') . $EncodeImage . ('&captions=') . $EncodeCC . ('&logo=') . $EncodeLogo;
$iframejw8 = $dominio . ('embed.php?id=') . ($jw8);
$iframejw7 = $dominio . ('embed.php?id=') . ($jw7);
?>
```

Comment: Você precisa verificar se cada valor que está recebendo está mesmo sendo passado. Algo como `if (isset($_POST['parametro'])) { ...`. (E pra quê tanto parêntese nesse código! Não precisa colocar as strings entre parênteses!)

Comment: Um atalho – que nesse caso específico de uso considero válido – é simplesmente suprimir o erro "na raiz" com `@`. Por exemplo: `$encodeAuto = @$_POST['Auto'];`.

Comment: Certo, irei tentar, os parenteses foi por conta que todo código tava encriptado em base64, fiz a decriptação e acabei deixando os parenteses ainda

Comment: Funcionou, creio que como não é algo que ira importar muito posso deixar desta forma, obrigada! :D

Comment: Suprimir erros nunca é algo válido... Sugiro resolver o problema de verdade (verificando se todos os campos existem no POST para, só então, tentar usar essas variáveis. Além do mais, usar `extract($_POST)` é uma péssima abordagem, por motivos descritos [aqui](https://davidnoren.com/post/php-extract-vulnerability.html) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837789/how-to-demonstrate-an-exploit-of-extract-post).

Comment: Sofia, recomendo a leitura de https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php para você entender o que está fazendo. @HélitonMartins eu sei que é uma opinião polêmica, mas acho mesmo válido suprimir o erro ao acessar $_POST apenas para atribuir seu valor a uma variável, como no exemplo do meu comentário acima. Sobre o extract estou totalmente de acordo com você.

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendo o ponto e não acredito que o @ seja um crime por si só (embora a tendência a se tornar um seja muito grande)... Só que, nesse caso, os erros não estão sendo disparados por algo do tipo `$encodeAuto = $_POST['Auto'];` (o que geraria um `Notice: Undefined Index`), mas pela utilização de variáveis não declaradas (que, aí sim, gera um `Notice: undefined variable`) nas últimas linhas, na hora de definir `$jw7` e `$jw8`...

Comment: @HélitonMartins É verdade, não prestei muita atenção no código. Então, dependendo de onde ela colocou a @ para resolver, pode mesmo ter sido um crime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está usando variáveis que você não tem certeza que existem (porque você só as declara quando o `$_POST` contém as chaves que você quer, mas as utiliza independentemente de ter ou não declarado).

Além disso, utilizar `extract($_POST)` é uma péssima abordagem, por motivos descritos [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837789/how-to-demonstrate-an-exploit-of-extract-post) e [aqui](https://davidnoren.com/post/php-extract-vulnerability.html).

Isto posto, eu sugiro o seguinte *refactoring* para seu código:

```php
<?php
function base64(string $string) : string
{
    $encrypt_method = ('AES-256-CBC');
    $secret_key = ('altere-a-chave');
    $secret_iv = ('altere-a-chave');
    $key = hash(('sha256'), $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash(('sha256'), $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    return openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
}
   
if (empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST['Auto'], $_POST["FullHD"], $_POST["HD"], $_POST["M_SD"], $_POST["LOW"], $_POST["title"], $_POST["description"], $_POST["background"], $_POST["captions"], $_POST["SiteLogo"])) {
    // Bad request...
    echo('<style>#preview{display:none !important;}</style>');
    $buttonStatus = 'Start Encrypt';
    $buttonColor = '#656565';
} else {
    // Good request!
    echo('<style>#preview{display:block !important;}</style>');
    $buttonStatus = 'Encrypted';
    $buttonColor = '#337ab7';
    
    // Get POST data
    $EncodeAuto = $_POST['Auto'];
    $EncodeFull = $_POST["FullHD"];
    $EncodeHD = $_POST["HD"];
    $EncodeSD = $_POST["M_SD"];
    $EncodeLOW = $_POST["LOW"];
    $EncodeTitle = $_POST["title"];
    $EncodeDesc = $_POST["description"];
    $EncodeImage = $_POST["background"];
    $EncodeCC = $_POST["captions"];
    $EncodeLogo = $_POST["SiteLogo"];
    
    // Do whatever you're doing...
    $jw7 = $dominio . 'admin/encrypt/jw7.php?auto=' . $EncodeAuto . '&fullhd=' . $EncodeFull . '&hd=' . $EncodeHD . '&m_sd=' . $EncodeSD . '&low=' . $EncodeLOW . '&title=' . $EncodeTitle . '&desc=' . $EncodeDesc . '&background=' . $EncodeImage . '&captions=' . $EncodeCC . '&logo=' . $EncodeLogo;
    $jw8 = $dominio . 'admin/encrypt/jw8.php?auto=' . $EncodeAuto . '&fullhd=' . $EncodeFull . '&hd=' . $EncodeHD . '&m_sd=' . $EncodeSD . '&low=' . $EncodeLOW . '&title=' . $EncodeTitle . '&desc=' . $EncodeDesc . '&background=' . $EncodeImage . '&captions=' . $EncodeCC . '&logo=' . $EncodeLogo;
    $iframejw8 = $dominio . 'embed.php?id=' . $jw8;
    $iframejw7 = $dominio . 'embed.php?id=' . $jw7;
}
```

Note que eu juntei seus vários ifs fazendo a mesma verificação em apenas um bloco if/else, removi o temido `extract()` verificando se tudo existe no `$_POST` e depois atribuindo cada um à sua variável.

Comment: Agradeço pelo trabalho que fez, irei estudar como cada elemento funciona para entender isso melhor futuramente, obrigada